# Account Authorization for Google Drive Api

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-account

I am developing an android application that has the potential to provide large amount of statistical information. I want to save this data on my google drive to be analyzed later.

However, I am new to Google apis and have little to no idea how to authorize my account programatically. Here is what I have so far.

```
private static Uri driveUri;
private static Drive service;
private GoogleAccountCredential credential;
private Account driveAccount;

//      AccountManager accManager = 
//              (AccountManager) getSystemService(Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
//      accManager.setUserData(driveAccount, ???, ???)



    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName("myaccount@gmail.com");

    service = getDriveService(credential);

public class UploadToDrive extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        File sdcard = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        File fileAnalytics = null;
        try {
            fileAnalytics = File.createTempFile("Sessions" + File.separator + "session_" + timeStamp, ".txt", sdcard);
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        PrintStream ps = null;
        try {
            ps = new PrintStream(fileAnalytics);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        ps.println("Count: " + count);
        ps.println("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        ps.close();
        FileContent content = new FileContent("text/plain", fileAnalytics);

        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
        body.setTitle(fileAnalytics.getName());
        body.setMimeType("text/plain");


        try {
            service.files().insert(body, content);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }


}
```

The code runs sucessfully and the file is created on the device but I want to send it to my google drive.

I think the main problem is that I don't know what the account **name** credential is supposed to be. I have a feeling that it isn't "myacc@gmail.com". Is there any way I can obtain the account name string for my own google account?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that Google Drive, Dropbox, and other cloud services don't have built in support for accessing your own account.

And even if I did get my account key, it changes every 15 minutes!

I suggest setting up a website and using FTP to upload files.